# ECR にある docker image の取得方法

Tags: docker, aws-ecr

mlflow sagemaker というコマンドで
AWS ECR に自動生成された docker image に変更を加えたいです

https://qiita.com/3utama/items/b19e2239edb6996a735f
こちらを参考にしてとりあえずローカルにイメージを取得しようとしたのですがうまくいきません

実行した手順は

`docker pull ************.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/【イメージ名】:latest`
を実行したところ(イメージ ARN は AWS コンソールからのコピペなので間違ってないはず)

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied. ... repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your Authorization Token has expired. Please run 'aws ecr get-login --no-include-email' to fetch a new one.
```

というエラーが出て

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email
```

を実行したところ

```
docker login -u AWS -p xxxxxxx
```

という長いパスワードを持ったログインコマンドが表示されます

そのコマンドを実行したところ
`Login Succeeded`
となりました

再度
`docker pull ************.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/【イメージ名】:latest`
を実行したところ

```
Error response from daemon: ... manifest unknown: Requested image not found
```

といわれてしまいます

manifest ファイルというのがよくわからないのですが
イメージ側の作り方に問題があって必要なファイルが不足しているということなんでしょうか？

ECR の中のイメージに修正を加えるにはどういう手順を踏めばいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`manifest unknown: Requested image not found` というエラーメッセージは、典型的には指定した名前のイメージが存在しないときに出るものです。考えられる原因としてたとえば、`latest` という名前のタグは push されていますか？　ブラウザ上の [ECR コンソール](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-info.html)で確認するか、[`aws ecr list-images`](https://qiita.com/fk_2000/items/bffd3b1ad6f3ab109766) コマンドを使って現在どのようなイメージが ECR にあるか確認してみてください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りタグ名が違っていました。